# Image border issue

Tags: html, css

***HTML***

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-logo"><u><a href="#">MMH</a></u></div>
            <div class="header-inner"><a href="#">Miami Max Hydro</a></div>
            <nav class="header-nav">
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>
    </div>
        <div class="homepage">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="images">
                    <div class="column">
                        <div class="profile-large">
                            <div class="column1">
                                <div class="profile-overlay">
                                    <div class="column1">
                                    <img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,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 />

                                    <div class="column2">
                                        <p>Cell2</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column3">
                                        <p>Cell3</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
```

***CSS:***

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://weknowyourdreamz.com/images/sea/sea-08.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    back
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #D2F0C6;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    border: 6px solid #80bc80;
}
.header-inner {
    Margin-top: 10px;

}
.images {
    padding: 20px;
}
.header-inner a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.header-logo {
    font-size: 32px;
    Font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.header-logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
.header-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #295f6f;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.header-nav {
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
..images {
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.column {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.profile-overlay {
    float: left;
    border: 6px solid #80bc80;
    width: 255px;
    height: 245px;
}
```

***My Issue:***

Basically, No matter what I do to get a border around my image, I get[image: this]

Basically the top border extends behind the header.

I've tried *margin-top* with no success, it just keeps the picture in the same spot relative to the border while pushing the top of the border down.

*line-height* won't work either. *Even line-height 1* will instantly make the picture match the top border but go away from the bottom and hide under the header.

I do have an idea in mind, doing *line-height 1* then doing some command to move the whole border/picture down relative to the body, but I don't know any code that does that.

Comment: You do realize that fixed positioning is used on the header and that the header will always stay fixed and on top, rest of the content will go behind right? The margin needs to be added to the sibling of the header but even then it will go behind once you start scrolling the page.

Comment: `box-model:border-box`

Comment: No no no, I know that, but I can't figure out how to make the top of the border fit tight on top of the image.

Comment: @BOTIrwin: Can't you give your header a fixed height value in pixels?

Comment: @Harry No I tried that. If I do something like height: 200px, it will always have the top of the border start way above the top of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/Lzsk4xfd/).

Remove `border: 6px solid #80bc80;` for `.profile-overlay` and add it to `.column1 img`.

```
.column1 img {
  border: 6px solid #80bc80;
}
```

Comment: YES THANK OMG =DDD